# EventMachine HTTP Request can't connect behind proxy via HTTPS

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I'm working with em-http, but I cannot get HTTPS(SSL) connection behind proxy. Here is my code.

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'

url = "https://twitter.com/"
opts = {
  :proxy => { :host => 'my.proxy', :port => 8080 }
}

EventMachine.run do
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url, opts).get
  http.callback {
    puts http.response
    EventMachine.stop
  }
end
```

This code works without errors, but it does nothing and does not quit from eventmachine main loop.

When I try it under conditions like below, my app can connect to the target.

- outside proxy / via HTTPS
- behind proxy / via HTTP

I can also get response using curl behind proxy.

```
curl "https://twitter.com/"
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You could consider adding a timeout to the get request, so that at least the app doesn't hang forever. Change your line to read  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url, opts).get, :timeout => 15

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, I was unable to get the proxied ssl requests to work with my http proxy but I was able to get it to work with a socks5 proxy:

```
:proxy => { :host => 'my.proxy', :port => 8080, :type => :socks5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the call:

```
http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get opts
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain a bit more why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Specify an `errback`.  Your code will then exit the event loop and also print any problems the proxy request may be having:

```
http.errback {
  p http.response_header.status
  p http.response_header
  p http.response

  EventMachine.stop
}
```